# mypy ignoring error in regular method but raising an error in __init__

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I have a class that looks as following:

```
from typing import Optional
import numpy as np

class TestClass():
    def __init__(self, a: Optional[float] = None):
        self.a = np.radians(a)
```

This returns the error `Argument 1 to "__call__" of "ufunc" has incompatible type "Optional[float]"; expected "Union[Union[int, float, complex, str, bytes, generic], Sequence[Union[int, float, complex, str, bytes, generic]], Sequence[Sequence[Any]], _SupportsArray]"`

However, the following class passes through with no issues even though it essentially does the same thing:

```
from typing import Optional
import numpy as np

class TestClass():
    def __init__(self, a: Optional[float] = None):
        self.a = a

    def test(self):
        b = np.radians(self.a)
```

Using `np.radians(None)` has no effect on it either. How do I get mypy to recognize that this should also cause an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined an unchecked function, since you didn't annotate anything, `mypy` *doesn't type check `test`, just add an annotation:

```
from typing import Optional
import numpy as np

class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, a: Optional[float] = None):
        self.a = a

    def test(self) -> None:
        b = np.radians(self.a)
```

And you get the expected error

```
(py39) jarrivillaga-mbp16-2019:~ jarrivillaga$ mypy test_typing.py
test_typing.py:9: error: Argument 1 to "__call__" of "ufunc" has incompatible type "Optional[float]"; expected "Union[Union[int, float, complex, str, bytes, generic], Sequence[Union[int, float, complex, str, bytes, generic]], Sequence[Sequence[Any]], _SupportsArray]"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Note also, if you had used `mypy --strict` it would have been caught:

```
(py39) jarrivillaga-mbp16-2019:~ jarrivillaga$ mypy --strict test_typing.py
test_typing.py:8: error: Function is missing a return type annotation
test_typing.py:8: note: Use "-> None" if function does not return a value
test_typing.py:9: error: Argument 1 to "__call__" of "ufunc" has incompatible type "Optional[float]"; expected "Union[Union[int, float, complex, str, bytes, generic], Sequence[Union[int, float, complex, str, bytes, generic]], Sequence[Sequence[Any]], _SupportsArray]"
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```